# How to parse mathematical expressions

Tags: java, formula, expression-evaluation

I'd like to understand how a Java program like GeoGebra can read a mathematical expression like `exp(z^2)` from a textbox and then evaluate it. For those familiar with MatLab: How do you implement function handles in Java?

Comment: Regarding parsing: Have a look at Antlr -- http://www.antlr.org/

Comment: http://dev.geogebra.org/trac has the sources. read it from there.  Your question in current form has no value for future visitor. Please check the sources and comeback with more specific question.

Comment: Duplicate, yes, but not a real question? You must be kidding. We wouldn't have got as far as Fortran I without questions like these.

Comment: You need to look up 'recursive descent expression parser' and the Dijkstra Shunting-Yard Algorithm.

Comment: I agree this is a perfectly valid question about how to parse expressions in strings, it leads on to lots of compiler writing principles. Pointing at Shunting Yard (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is a good start.

Comment: Well, if that is not a question for StackOverflow, where do I go with questions like this!? And for yan: Your comment in the current form has no value for future visitors. Please check the sources and come back with a more specific link as to WHERE in the load of code the answer can be found.

Comment: Around here: http://dev.geogebra.org/trac/browser/trunk/geogebra/common/src/geogebra/common/kernel/commands/AlgebraProcessor.java

Answer (score 0):

If it is like evaluating mathematical expressions (INFIX), using java, I would recommend a simple approach by first converting the expression to POSTFIX notation and then following the basic algorithm for evaluating POSTFIX.

Take a look here

1. Expression is **A*B+C**
2. POSTFIX will be **AB*C+**
3. Read the postfix string, if operand, push it into stack. (IN stack -> **A,B**)
4. If operator(*****), pop out the two operands, perform the calculation (**A*B = E,say**).
5. PUSH the result **E** in stack
6. Goto step 3.

The End result in the stack would be your answer.